# jsTree - dragged node should not become a child

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Hy, I am using jsTree, but I am not an expert in jQuery stuff. What I want is, when using the drag and drop functionality of jsTree, I want that a node cannot be moved to another node's child list. A node can only be dragged to a parent position. I hope the question is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have anything we could start with? Any code? Anything you have tried already?

Comment: return false in drop callback if selected node level is less than target node. use node.get_path().length